# Show that binary words with the same numbers of 0s and 1s are countable by finding bijection from the natural numbers to the set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider all finite binary words that have the same number of zeroes as ones (ex: 0101). How can we show that this is countable?

I have tried listing some words in lexicographic order, but I don't see any pattern. Any recommendations on how to approach this problem?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & ... \\ \hline
 01& 10 & 0011 & 0101 & 0110 & 1001 & 1010 & 1100 & ... \\ \hline
\end{array}

EDIT: What I am looking for is how to define the specific bijection to natural numbers, I think that is different than Cantor.

Comment: @Rob: Not if an explicit bijection is wanted.

Comment: @Rob: It doesn’t hurt, but I don’t agree: I think my reading the obvious one.

Comment: @Rob: The title is clear, and the work in the question clearly shows an attempt to find a bijection. I agree that the question could be improved by making this explicit, but I still think that the intent is obvious.

Comment: I have edited the title and question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if $X$ is infinite and you have an injection $f : X \to \Bbb{N}$, then you can define a bijection $g$ between $X$ and $\Bbb{N}$ by defining $g(x)$ to be the number of natural numbers $i$ such that $i < f(x)$ and $i$ is in the range of $f$ (i.e., define $g(x)$ so that $f(x)$ is the $g(x)$-th element of the range of $f$ taken in ascending order). So as your set of binary words with equal numbers of $0$s and $1$s is infinite, it's enough to give an injection from the set of all binary words to $\Bbb{N}$ (since that restricts to an injection on your set). There are lots of ways of doing this. E.g., ternary representation is a cute one: change the $0$s and $1$s to $1$s and $2$s and view the result as a ternary representation of a natural numbers. So $010$ represents $27 + 6 + 1 = 34$. This gives an injection from which you can extract the bijection you are looking for.

Comment: Colloquially,let g(x)=n when f(x) is the nth least element of the image of f.

Comment: @user254665: thanks. I've tried to improve things in the answer.